# Add summary at the group footer based in a second field, Crystal Reports, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

Hello and I hope my question is clear.
I have a report that gets the data this way:

Office 1
 Document 1   some data .... Document Type A 
 Document 2   some data .... Document Type Z 
 Document 3   some data .... Document Type A 
 Document 4   some data .... Document Type B 
 Document 5   some data .... Document Type D 
 Document 6   some data .... Document Type Z 
 
Office 2
 Document 7   some data .... Document Type A
 Document 8   some data .... Document Type A
 Document 9   some data .... Document Type B
 Document10   some data .... Document Type B
 Document11   some data .... Document Type C
 Document12   some data .... Document Type D

**Where Office is the Group, now I need add a summary in the footer of each group, showing the total count per Document Type**

Office 1
 Document 1   some data .... Document Type A
 Document 2   some data .... Document Type Z
 Document 3   some data .... Document Type A
 Document 4   some data .... Document Type B
 Document 5   some data .... Document Type D
 Document 6   some data .... Document Type Z
      -----------------------------------------

Document Type A: 2
      Document Type B: 1
      Document Type D: 1
      Document Type Z: 2
 ----------------------------------------------
  
Office 2
 Document 7   some data .... Document Type A
 Document 8   some data .... Document Type A
 Document 9   some data .... Document Type B
 Document10   some data .... Document Type B
 Document11   some data .... Document Type C
 Document12   some data .... Document Type D
      ----------------------------------------- 
      Document Type A: 2
      Document Type B: 2
      Document Type C: 1
      Document Type D: 1
 ----------------------------------------------

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what do you mean second field?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
1.) Running Total Field.
2.) Evalute ==> On change group ==> select your group created with field.
3.) Drag total on report footer.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need the summary under each group footer, not under at the end of the report thanks anyway

Comment: its the same way.. just try it.. drag the summary in the group you created

Answer (score 0):

Take a subreport on group footer. In subreport add group of document type and take a count of document type.